# Is there a way to move cells to the left when a sheet is copied?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a 5 week look ahead labor planner. I currently have a function that displays weeks 2-5 from the previous sheet to weeks 1-4 on the copied sheet. The issue is when a task is finished or another task is inserted, the formula changes.

For example, the formula in C8 would display =Prev(I8). If a task is inserted and row 8 moves to row 9, the formula changes to =Prev(I9) causing the former row 8 to display row 9 of the previous sheet.

What I am looking for is a trigger event when a certain sheet is copied or a way to permanently and automatically copying the previous cells instead of using a formula.

Example of the sheets:

sheet 1: https://imgur.com/w2Sk8f9
copied sheet: https://imgur.com/TwWkfzZ

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can build a click button that deletes the value in week 1 and pastes the others to the left

```
Sub example() 
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F150").Clear
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:Z150").Copy 
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
End Sub
```

Change the range, and get your result. Hope it is helpful.